# regular expression to replace number with currency

Tags: c#, regex, currency

I need some help using a regular expression to reformat a number into currency.  My input will be something either like the string "123" or "123.45".  I would want to replace "123" with "123.00" and leave "123.45" as is.  The regular expression will also be used to validate input, so both "123" and "123.45" should match.  I have already done something like this with a SSN where I reformat a 9-digit string into nnn-nn-nnnn format, but the currency string is stumping me.

For the SSN my regular expression and replacement string were these:

`((?!(000|666))([0-8]\d{2}))-?((?!00)\d{2})-?((?!0000)\d{4})$`

`$1-$4-$5`

This is the regular expression I'm trying (can even deal with commas) 
`([0-9]{1,3}(?:,?[0-9]{3})*)((?:\.[0-9]{2})?)$`

where in the replacement $1 is the part before the . and $2 is after.  I want the replacement string to show $2 if there is something or ".00" if $2 is blank.  How do I do it?

Edit to add more context:  Let me explain why I am trying to do it this way.  I have some code to go to the database and get some strings and display them.  I deliberately don't know or care what those strings are.  I can also edit those strings in a text box.  Then people started asking for the strings to be displayed in a different format than they are stored.  First it started with a string representing the SSN where 123456789 should be displayed, and edited, in the format 123-45-6789.  So I wrote some code to allow me to define a regex string and a replacement string, for each database string.  These strings accomplish the reformatting, plus the regex string is used to validate the input from the text box.  And all this worked fine for the SSN string, using the regex and replacement I listed above.  Now they want to display the string representing currency "123" as "123.00".  So I have the infrastructure to support this, if I can come up with the right regex string and replacement string.  My code doesn't know this is currency.  It just knows it's a generic string that should be rewritten before being displayed.

Comment: With what scripting or programming language are you using regex?

Comment: I am using C#.  Here is the sample code:                      `Regex regex = new Regex(regExpressionString, RegexOptions.Compiled);
val = regex.Replace(val, replacementString);`

Comment: You cannot (easily) do conditionals with Regex, that is outside the scope of what Regex was designed to do. As soon as you said "I want this if this is blank, or this otherwise", you have now gone beyond what Regex is reasonably capable of doing. Instead of trying to shove all your functionality into Regex's limited capacity, why not leverage the incredibly powerful and versatile language at your disposal (C#) and parse your string that way?

Comment: Ha!  At this point, I see it's not easy, but I'll settle for difficult, if it works.  At this point, I'm stuck shoving the functionality into regex, as you say.  I found this page http://manual.macromates.com/en/regular_expressions that seems to suggest a (?2:abcd) replacement syntax, at the bottom of the page, but so far it's not working for me.  It just replaces it like that literally.  Has anyone seen this syntax before?

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't use a regex, I'd use the built-in formatting library.

```
Decimal number;
if( !Decimal.TryParse( inputNumberAsString, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, NumberFormat.Number, out number ) {
    // Handle error
}

return number.ToString( CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, "c" );
```

Comment: True, there are many ways to do this particular case more easily without a regex.  But I have a setup where I must take any generic string, that I don't know anything about, and rewrite / validate it using only a regex string and display it with a replacment string.

Comment: @user3023330 then please rewrite your question so that it reflects the original problem, not this specific case.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow.  My original problem is that I would like to use a regex to validate and reformat my string, but I cannot figure what my matching string and replacemenet string should be.  But I will go back and edit the original problem to clarify that my input is a string.

Comment: @user3023330 I mean, rewrite your question so you can accept any string, not just for numbers and currency.